# How to add a suffix to the "Feed Item" comments

Tags: php, string, str-replace, feed

I searched an could not find a way to do the following string edit. Any help would be appreciated.

**Part 1**

Currently my Feed Aggregator outputs a single **$content** variable's that contains the following HTML code:

This example shows just three feed items.

```
$content = '

<!-- ---------- Feed Item ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

<!-- ---------- Feed Item ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

<!-- ---------- Feed Item ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

';
```

I would like to echo the **$content** variable to yield the following with sequence numbers added as a suffix to the "Feed Item" comments as shown below:

Keep in mind that there can be 100's of feed items.

```
<!-- ---------- Feed Item 1 ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

<!-- ---------- Feed Item 2 ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

<!-- ---------- Feed Item 3 ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah 
</div>
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?
I am assuming it would involve a loop some how...

**Part 2 (optional but eventual)**

The next step would then insert some additional content such as `<div>Blah Blah Blah</div>` between two feed items like Feed Item 2 and Feed Item 3 as shown below.

In addition, I would like to be able to choose what feed items to insert the additional content between, i.e. items 7 and 8, or 10 and 11.

```
<!-- ---------- Feed Item 1 ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

<!-- ---------- Feed Item 2 ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah
</div>

<div>Blah Blah Blah</div>

<!-- ---------- Feed Item 3 ---------- -->
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Blah Blah, divs, h3, links, etc... Blah Blah 
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: edit the "Feed Aggregator" (what ever that is) not its output

Comment: I cannot edit the Feed Aggregator. It's part of an auto-updated CMS system. I already edited the output to get what you see here at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Exactly - for help with this we'll need the code generating this HTML. Coming at it from after it is generated will be much rougher, but if necessary it would be easier to do in JavaScript.

Comment: Is there always <!-- ---------- Feed Item ---------- --> before each item?

Comment: Yes, I added via php <!-- ---------- Feed Item ---------- --> to the output to separate the feed items using $content = str_ireplace('<div style', "\r\n<!-- ---------- Feed Item ---------- -->\r\n<div style", $content);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode the string by the comment and replace the word `Feed Item` with `Feed Item X`

```
$i = 0;
$newcontent = '';
foreach(explode('Feed Item',$content) as $eachContent){
    $i++;
    $newcontent .= str_replace("<!-- ----------", "<!-- ---------- Feed Item $i", $eachContent);

}
```

Comment: Glad It helped!

Comment: Now do I need to check the up arrow on the answer?

Comment: I found a solution to Part 2. Thanks to everybody for your help